# Custom Search for WordPress Custom Post Type page

Tags: wordpress, search, post, custom-post-type

I've got a fairly simple problem, which I would expect would have been fairly common, but after hours of searching and testing, I'm a bit stuck.

All I am trying to do it extend the search capability of the default 'Search Posts' function on my Custom Post Type page. Here is my code, but it is returning nothing when I do a search for a known email address. I get the feeling I might be barking up the wrong tree entirely. Can anyone recommend a solution...

```
function iymp_modify_mp_posts_search($query) {

    /*
     * If admin and if my custom post type
     */
    if (is_admin() && $query->query_vars['post_type'] === 'mp_post') {

        /*
         * Show 200 posts per page in ascending order
         */
        $query->set('posts_per_page', '200');
        $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );

        /*
         * If user entered a search term
         */
        if (isset($_GET['s'])) {
            /*
             * As well as searching in the title (default behaviour), search in
             * the _email_key field as well.
             * *** Doesn't work ***
             */
            $query->query_vars['meta_query'][] = array(
                'key' => '_email_key',
                'value' => $_GET['s'],
                'compare' => 'LIKE',
            );

        }   
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'iymp_modify_mp_posts_search' );
```

Maybe the problem is that WP is ANDing the searches in the title and _email_key fields. If that's the problem, how would I OR them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was indeed that WP does an AND search in the title and _email_key fields.

To do an OR search, I tried merging WP_Query results as shown here - https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/55519/can-i-merge-2-new-wp-queryvariable-s - in guidod's answer. That wasn't a great solution though, and resulted in erratic behaviour.

The correct solution I found was to modify the query using the WP Custom Query as shown in the code (which requires some modifications) here - http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Queries ..